# Range-based for loop ambiguity in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

These two pieces of code:

A)

```
void KMeans<N>::assign_pixels_to_clusters()
{
    for (auto cluster : clusters)
    {
        cluster.clear_pixels();
    }

    for (auto pixel : pixels)
    {
        float min_distance = FLT_MAX;
        Cluster<N> c;

        for (auto cluster : clusters)
        {
            float distance = norm(
                pixel.get_value(),
                cluster.get_centroid()
            );

            if (distance < min_distance)
            {
                min_distance = distance;
                c = cluster;
            }
        }

        c.add_pixel(pixel);
    }
}
```

and B)

```
template <size_t N>
void KMeans<N>::assign_pixels_to_clusters()
{
    for (auto cluster : clusters)
    {
        cluster.clear_pixels();
    }

    for (auto pixel : pixels)
    {
        float min_distance = FLT_MAX;
        int idx = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_clusters; i++)
        {
            float distance = norm(
                pixel.get_value(),
                clusters[i].get_centroid()
            );

            if (distance < min_distance)
            {
                min_distance = distance;
                idx = i;
            }
        }

        clusters[idx].add_pixel(pixel);
    }
}
```

seem similar to me, yet only B) works the way I want to. In the case of A), the pixels are not assigned to clusters at all. After the piece of code A) is run, the clusters are empty and have no pixels assigned to them. Can you help me understand why, please?

Comment: I do not understand. Yes, `Cluster<N> c;` is a different separate object then `clusters[idx]`.

Comment: Your range-for loops are odd. It seems you want `for(auto &cluster:clusters)`. The first loop does nothing as written.

Comment: @KamilCuk ```clusters``` is a vector of objects of type ```Cluster<N>```

Comment: @cigien can you please explain to me why is the ```&``` operator needed? I am completely new to the object-oriented side of C++ and some things are a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I've answered this particular question, but I would suggest picking a nice [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learning concepts from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `A` version, you are making a copy of the cluster on this line:

```
c = cluster;
```

So when you do

```
c.add_pixel(pixel);
```

you are not changing the `clusters` range.

For the same reason, this loop:

```
for (auto cluster : clusters)
    {
        cluster.clear_pixels();
    }
```

doesn't actually clear pixels of any cluster in `clusters`, since each `cluster` is a copy. If you actually want to *refer* to each cluster in `clusters`, you need to do this:

```
for (auto & cluster : clusters)
    {
        cluster.clear_pixels();
    }
```